# Matlab plot3 for specific point

Tags: matlab

I am problem with `plot3`.

I have `X`, `Y` and `TIME` which are `32656*1` double matrix and I used `plot3(X,Y,TIME);`.

Now I have a value taken from `TIME`.

How can I plot that on the graph like scatter?

Comment: Do you want something that looks like a normal `X` and `Y` plot with a `TIME` scatter plot transposed over it?

Comment: @JamesTaylor, My aim is plotting continuous X,Y and Time, then point out specific points by given Time value

Comment: So to be more explicit, which values to do want on the X axis of the graph and which values do the want to be on the Y axis of the graph? Also, what is `TIME` formatted in? Do you need to convert it? Do you want `X` and `Y` as a function of time, [like this](http://peltiertech.com/images/2009-01/Lines2007ABSecondary.png)?

Comment: What do you mean like `scatter`? Do you want to plot all `X`s and `Y`s for that particular value of `TIME` and the plot should be a scatter plot, is this what you want?

Answer (score 0):

I feel like I should give this an answer addressing what I think is the problem, although the wording in the question is still a bit unclear.

Given a data set `X` and `Y` plotted over `TIME` values, you could plot the data on the same graph using `hold`, like so:

```
%// Plots the data in a new figure window
figure;
hold on;
scatter(TIME, X);
scatter(TIME, Y);

hold off;
```

Or alternatively:

```
%// Plots the data in a new figure window
figure;
hold on;
plot(TIME, X, 'o', TIME, Y, 'o');

hold off;
```

Then simply convert the time value so they display properly on the axis of the graph, like so:

```
%// Convert the time values
set(gca, 'XTickLabel', datestr(TIME, 'HH:MM PM'));
```

If you haven't parsed the raw data yet and it contains date strings, you also have to call this before you plot it, adjusting it to fit your data:

```
TIME = datenum(DATA{1});
```